# WSL Debian not connecting to internet

Tags: debian, networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to start using WSL Debian, but it appears that it's not connected to the internet. Commands like `sudo ping www.google.com` and `sudo apt-get update` are not working.

```
user@USER:~$ sudo ping www.google.com
[sudo] password for user:
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
user@USER:~$ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
Err:3 http://ftp.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ftp.debian.org'
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ftp.debian.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I looked at changing the template file for `/etc/resolv.conf` [like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135932/apt-get-update-failure-to-fetch-cant-connect-to-any-sources) but it didn't do anything different. This worked temporarily when I called wsl from a powershell to open up Ubuntu, but it didn't do anything for Debian. This has also now stopped working for the powershell and I'm not sure why.

`/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
user@USER:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main
```

I reinstalled WSL and attempted the same actions, but unfortunately, it did not work.

Contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Include the contents of `resolv.conf`. You do not have any working nameservers configured. Be aware that `resolv.conf` is autogenerated in wsl (can be disabled in `/etc/wsl.conf`)

Comment: @Panki done, and yeah I understood that. This is the case even after I changed it.